# cannot open a ready xlsx file(excel)

Tags: php, excel

I have a ready xlsx file and I want to open it it is in the current directory where I wrote the code I tried to use this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="03_prod_reserves.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2010');
$objWriter->save('03_prod_reserves.xlsx');
  exit;
```

also I used this:

```
header('Content-type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="03_prod_reserves.xlsx"');
readfile("03_prod_reserves.xlsx", "r");
```

none of them worked I don't know whats the problem I have the error :

[image]

if I do this:

```
echo '<br><a href="03_prod_reserves.xlsx">Open Previous</a>';
```

I have problem I cannot see the file with the data but I want to open it instantley when refreshing the page, not clicking on it

Comment: and what happens when you open your xlsx file with Excel, before sending it to the client ?

Comment: don't open the file in excel directly. save it to disk, see what's inside. maybe it's not an Excel file, and is nothing but some PHP error messages.

Comment: Right click, properties, click "Unblock", Apply. It should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first header by this

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
```

Comment: actually it seems working but it says excel found unreadable content yes or no and then if i click yes it will show the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/files/) to read xls files. Or you can covert them to a csv file and just use the built in `fgetcsv` shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)